# What to do with old low-quality post?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

Today [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444086/find-the-equation-of-the-line-thru-a-point-forming-with-axes-a-triangle-given-an) appeared in my Low Quality Posts queue. The description said that someone flagged it as low-quality.

In case it gets deleted, here's the content:

> Find the equation of the line through $(2,2)$ and forming with the axes a triangle of area $9$.

The post dates 15 july 2013 (almost two years ago).

In my honest opinion, it does not satisfy the current definition of "on-topic", because it's a homework question that does not show any effort towards the solution of the problem. However, I ignore whether it was considered off-topic at the time it was written, seeing that it has 3 answers too.

I skipped the review, but questions are:

- Should I have recommended deletion as off-topic?
- More generally, do quality standards work retroactively?

**Added**: To be fair, in the comments there was a vague reference by the OP to an "intercept method", so the answer to the first question might be *No* (or, at least, someone could argue over the presence of a tiny effort).
Let's say that the question remains, but my example is not the best one.

Comment: This seems (at least to some extent) related: [Why close old questions with accepted answers using the “no context” reason?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19377/why-close-old-questions-with-accepted-answers-using-the-no-context-reason)

Comment: Thank you, @MartinSleziak, that pretty much cleared my doubts.